# Regular Expression to only allow numbers 3-9 if the leading character is zero

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, match

I am trying to validate a html text input's text to only allow the months of the year using a javascript function bound to the `input` event that `test` and `match` a Regular Expression (Regex) pattern.  
Although I managed to create a Regex that only allow 2 digits with or without leading zeros, but excludes two zeros following each other.  I cannot seem to get the Regex right to only allow the character 3-9 if the leading character is a zero.  This would mean that all months are included e.g. 01 to 12.
My Regex to `test`:
`^(?!00)[0-9][012]$` - this will not allow double zeros and only 012 as the second character.
My Regex to `match`:
`^[0-9][012]{0,1}$` - this will allow only two digits and only 012 as the second character.

> Critically this does not allow 03 to 09 but allows 01,02,10 to 12.

```
jsMod.eveOnlyTwoDigitAllowLead = function(evt)  {
    var evt = window.evt || evt;
    var valid = /^(?!00)[0-9][0-9]$/;
    var number = /^[0-9][0-9]{0,1}$/;
    if (!valid.test(this.value)) {
        var n = this.value.match(number);
        this.value = n ? n[0] : '';
   }
};
```

Something such as `^[0-9]([012]|[1-9]){0,1}$` I thought would work but it doesn't.
How do I change this Regex to only allow the characters 3-9 on the second character if the first is a leading zero?

Comment: If you match months, why not use `/^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/`?

Comment: If your input is type date there are validators there. No regex needed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks.  Your expression does match months but does not work in my function.

Comment: @JohnPeters My experience with the date type is it only gives a message of incorrect input.  I want a validator that removes wrong input or disallows invalid characters.  My dates have a separate  input for the year, month and date.